# Dynamically inserting into/updating a column that's using data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, ssms, sql-insert

I'm wanting to get the sum of all credits hours associated with each specific StudentID so each time I enroll a student into a course or even change the credit hours of any of the courses it updates the "TotalCreditHours" column.

```
INSERT INTO Student (StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, StudentEmail, 
    StudentPhoneNo, HomeState,
    BirthDate, Gender, TotalCreditHours, GPA, SemesterEnrolled, Program) 
    VALUES('Isiah', 'Thomas', 'ithomas058@msu.edu', '417-822-7732', 'MI', '08- 
    15-1994', 'M', 
    (SELECT SUM(CreditHours) FROM Enrolled JOIN Course ON Enrolled.CourseID = 
    Course.CourseID WHERE StudentID = 1), 3.3, 'Fall', 1)
```

[coursetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYd50.jpg)
[enrolledtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTtYw.jpg)
[studenttable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7uhn.jpg)

My query only works if the Enrolled table already has that StudentID in a course. It'll be NULL if I try to create the Student first then enroll them. I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically update the TotalCreditHours even if I created the Student first.

On the screenshot it shows "TotalCreditHours" as NOT NULL because ssms hasn't updated. It allows nulls so students with no credit hours yet can still be created.

Comment: What's wrong with NULL  "TotalCreditHours" for the newly inserted student ?

Comment: I don't get the question. I think having null credit hours until a student is enrolled into a course is fine

Comment: Neither do I. If you need current "TotalCreditHours" as other tables are updated, you have two options : don't store it at all. get it with VIEW, TVF,.... Otherwise create trigger on "Enrolled"

Answer (score 0):

You could use an  INSERT SELECT

```
INSERT INTO Student (StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, StudentEmail, 
StudentPhoneNo, HomeState,
BirthDate, Gender, TotalCreditHours, GPA, SemesterEnrolled, Program) 
SELECT 'Isiah', 'Thomas', 'ithomas058@msu.edu', '417-822-7732', 'MI', '08- 
15-1994', 'M', SUM(CreditHours) , 3.3, 'Fall', 1
FROM Enrolled 
JOIN Course ON Enrolled.CourseID = Course.CourseID 
WHERE StudentID = 1
```

but if you need  an update  (in mysql)

```
update  Student 
set  TotalCreditHours = (
    SELECT SUM(CreditHours) 
    FROM Enrolled JOIN Course ON Enrolled.CourseID =   Course.CourseID
    WHERE StudentID = 1)
where student.id = 1
```

Comment: Same results. It doesn't update whenever I enroll the student into another course

Comment: update ??   .. you want insert a row or updated  a row??

Comment: both.. I want to create dynamic insert that will update the TotalCreditHours column whenever the Enrolled table adds the StudentID 1 to another course